# how to sort the object array to map with respect to fields in object array using java script

Tags: javascript

I have an object array like this

```
[
      {bookName:"javascript",authorName:"john"},
      {bookName:"java",authorName:"peter"},
      {bookName:"j2ee",authorName:"john"},
      {bookName:".net",authorName:"peter"},
      {bookName:"oracle",authorName:"peter"}];
```

I tried the logics but i didnt get correctly.I want to sort out like this..

```
{
peter:{
    [{bookName:"java",authorName:"peter"},

    {bookName:".net",authorName:"peter"},

    {bookName:"oracle",authorName:"peter"} ]

     } ,
john :{
    [{bookName:"j2ee",authorName:"john"},

    {bookName:"javascript",authorName:"john"}]

    }

}.
```

how can i do that.. Thanks in Advance ..

```
var obj={};
var objArr = given objectarray;
for(var i=0;i<objArr.length.i++ ){
  objArr[objArr[i].authorName]=objArr[i];    
}
```

and

```
var obj={};
var objArr = given objectarray;
for(var i=0;i<objArr.length.i++ ){
  var arr=[];
  objArr[objArr[i].authorName]=arr.push(objArr[i]);    
}
```

Comment: How many logics did you try? Can you include them in your question?

Comment: Show the code you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var b = ... your object ...
var m = {};
b.map(function(v){(m[v.authorName]=m[v.authorName]||[]).push(v)});
```

[Demonstration (open the console)](http://jsfiddle.net/EFLJV/)

Comment: +1 - that's slick. Come on [reversal](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal)!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/azqRu/

```
var array = [
          {bookName:"javascript",authorName:"john"},
          {bookName:"java",authorName:"peter"},
          {bookName:"j2ee",authorName:"john"},
          {bookName:".net",authorName:"peter"},
          {bookName:"oracle",authorName:"peter"}
    ];

    var items = {};
    for(var i = 0, ii = array.length; i < ii; i++) {
        var cell = array[i];
        items[cell.authorName] = items[cell.authorName] || [];
        items[cell.authorName].push(cell);
    }    

    alert(items["peter"]);
```

Comment: thanks jension.. i got output